# Struggling to use the spread operator on style objects. I'm trying to retain multiple properties but can't figure out how to do so cleanly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-state-management, react-state

Classic to-do list project. I'm trying to update the state of my list item when I click on it as well as hover on/off. I'm struggling to retain all my previous properties when the state changes. So far, the only fix has been to specify each property in each function and give it prevValue if I don't want it to change. In my code below, I used this fix with my strikethrough textDecoration to illustrate when it works, but didn't use it for fontStyle and opacity to see what happens when I don't specify it or attempt an alternative method.

I imagine there's a much better way to do this, but I'm struggling to describe it well enough to find a good answer online. I figure it's something to do with the spread operator, but nothing has clicked for me so far. Thanks for your help!

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
 
function ToDoItem(props) {
  const [textStrike, setStrikeState] = useState(false);
 
  const [textStyle, setTextStyle] = useState({
    key: 0,
    textDecoration: "none",
    fontStyle: "normal",
    opacity: "1"
  });
 
 
 function handleClick(prevValue) {
   
    if (textStrike === false) {
      setTextStyle({  
        textDecoration: "line-through",
        fontStyle: "italic",
        opacity: "0.4"
      })} 
    else {
      setTextStyle({
        textDecoration: "none",
        fontStyle: "normal",
        opacity: "1"
      })}
 
    setStrikeState(prevValue => !prevValue);
    console.log("textStrike boolean value is " + textStrike);
  } 
 
 
 function hoverOnHandle(prevValue) {
   setTextStyle({
     textDecoration: prevValue,
     textShadow: "1px 1px lightgray"
   });
 }
 
 function hoverOffHandle(prevValue) {
   setTextStyle({
     textDecoration: prevValue,
     textShadow: ""
   });
 }
 
 
 return (
   <li
     onClick={handleClick} 
     onMouseOver={hoverOnHandle}
     onMouseOut={hoverOffHandle}
     style={textStyle}
   >
     {props.text}
   </li>
  );
 }
 
export default ToDoItem;
```

Comment: If you want to only update or add certain properties, you can use setTextStyle({ ...textStyle, yourProperty: yourValue })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only update or add certain properties, you can use

```
setTextStyle({ 
  ...textStyle,
  yourProperty: yourValue
})
```

For exmaple, if you want to update only the fontFamily, you can

```
setTextStyle({ 
      ...textStyle,
      fontFamily: 'Roboto'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you may do something like so:

```
setTextStyle({
    ...textStyle,
    key_we_wish_to_change:new value
      })
```

the spread operator will move the key-value pairs one by one to the new object, but since you are overwriting only one value, all the others remain the same.